# Undefined references in C Opengl

Tags: codeblocks

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

What could be the problem? Since I am new to C and opengl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply not linking the library. Your IDE will have a fiddly but functional way to link a third party library, generally it's buried away somewhere under "linker options" or something with a name like that.

Comment: I linked a library 'glut' which I downloaded earlier but its of no use.

Comment: So it's probably incompatible in some way. Normally Open GL is ready installed and you don't need to download. You need to fiddle with the linker until it links the correct library.